# Close.io API not loading all of the lead information

Tags: python, api, request

I am not receiving all of the leads from the Close.io API.

I am trying to obtain all of the urls of my leads in my Close.io, however, I only get the first 100. I want to make this number unlimited, however, it does not budge.

This is my code:
`

```
api = Client('API_KEY')

params = {
    '_fields':'url',
    '_results_limit': 698,
}

resp = api.get('lead', params=params)
```

Instead of API_KEY I have inserted my proper API key. I get a response from the API, however, I only obtain 100 different urls instead of the desired 698. Why is that the case?

The output looks something like this:

```
{'data': [{'url': 'https://www.example1.com/'}, ... {'url': 'https://www.example100.com'}, 'has_more': True, 'total_results': 698}
```

For reference: The Close.io API [documentation](https://developer.close.com/resources/leads/).